# Time Series Analysis using Fourier Technique

Tags: time-series, matlab, fourier-transform

i need to perform "Time Series Analysis" using Fourier Analysis/Technique on temperature data of 17 years. Their are four columns in it "Years", "Months", "Days" and "Temperature in C".
I need basic Tutorial/web-link or any thing useful which helps me step by step to do the Time Series.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic introduction to Fourier analysis, using R, is given [here](http://zoonek2.free.fr/UNIX/48_R/15.html#7). It shows R code to apply the fft function and plot outputs.